# C++ memberwise initialization and constructors

Tags: c++

Without defining a constructor I am able to use memberwise initialization:

```
struct B {
  A a_;
};
```

and later on it okay to say

```
B b {A()};
```

This is efficient as no copy or move of A is involved. However as soon as I define a move constructor for B the above code no longer compiles. How can I have both memberwise initialization and some constructors coexist?

Comment: Why would you define a user-defined move constructor?  Was the automatic one not fast enough for you?  Or do you have a pointer member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it is defined, `B` is an aggregate type if `A` is an aggregate type.

```
B b {A()};
```

is aggregate initialization.

When you add a move constructor to `B`, `B` stops being an aggregate type. Hence, you can't use aggregate initialization to initialize an instance of `B`.

From the standard (emphasis mine):

> **8.5.1 Aggregates** [dcl.init.aggr]
>
> 1 An *aggregate* is an array or a **class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors** (12.1), no *brace-or-equalinitializers* for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3)

Comment: I'm confused... According to your citation, `A` doesn't need to be aggregate for `B` to be aggregate, but you argue as it has to be.

Comment: "How can I have both memberwise initialization and some constructors coexist?" There still exists a way, you should mention it

Comment: @leemes: He only cited the relevent part of the definition, not the entire definition

Comment: Is there anyway to get the same efficiency as the aggregate initialization or is that not possible?

Comment: @MooingDuck What would be the way?

Comment: @fspeech: It's vaguely possible, but not with that syntax.  `B b {A()};` uses a "cheat" to construct the `A` directly, but if you have any explicit constructors the cheat no longer works.  You can specify a constructor of `B` that takes no (or variadic template list of) parameters that constructs the `A` though, that would net you the same efficiency.  The variadic template list only works if you have one parameter, unless you do _other_ tricks, which may add move constructor overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by R Sahu is already correct, but I'd like to add that there is no loss of efficiency to add a constructor that does what your memberwise-initialization does:

```
struct B {
  A a_;
  B(const A& a) : a_(a) {}
}
```

Now calling `B b {A()};` is exactly as efficient as it was when you were using aggregate-initialization.

UPDATE:
After reading the comments I've tested my assertion:

```
struct Foo
{
        Foo() { std::cout << "Foo default" << std::endl; }
        Foo(const Foo& other) { std::cout << "Foo copy" << std::endl; }
};

struct Bar
{
        Foo f;
        // #1 Bar(const Foo& f) : f(f) {}
};

int main()
{
        Bar b { Foo() };
}
```

As shown above this application outputs just

```
Foo default
```

If I uncomment #1 I then get

```
Foo default
Foo copy
```

as the original poster suggested (GCC 4.9 with -O3).  I have to play more with non-printing constructors to see if this is always true or just when there are side effects, but I wanted to update this post to clarify that it is not as cut and dry as I suggested.

Comment: I'm not convinced, I'm pretty sure this forces a pointless copy constructor.  Taking by value would minimize the inefficiency, but I don't think you can match it (outside of optional optimizations)

Comment: I just tried this: your answer calls A default, copy and destructor in that order, because a temporary in first created, while the memberwise initialization would skip generating the temporary and therefore saving a constructor and a destructor call.